# Why is my one-line equivalent to a function that appends a paragraph to a node not giving me the same results?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I've been following the [basic tutorial](https://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/) on Scala.js. In order to append a `<p>` tag to the body of my HTML page, the tutorial defines a function appendPar which appends a paragraph containing text to another node.

```
def appendPar(targetNode: dom.Node, text: String): Unit = {
    val parNode = document.createElement("p")
    val textNode = document.createTextNode(text)
    parNode.appendChild(textNode)
    targetNode.appendChild(parNode)
}
```

This function is called inside the main function of the TutorialApp to append `<p>Hello world</p>` to the body of the document. It worked fine when I tried it.

However, when I tried replacing the above code with a single line in main, `Hello world` was appended to the body, but not encapsulated in `<p>...</p>`.

```
document.body appendChild (document.createElement("p") appendChild 
    document.createTextNode("Hello world"))
```

As far as I can tell, my one-liner is equivalent to `appendPar(document.body, "Hello world")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really recommend that style of one-liner -- it's concise, but also confusing (mixing functional and side-effecting styles), and that's where your bug is coming from.

Ultimately, your inner block is returning the newly-created TextNode, so that's what is being used as the parameter to `document.body appendChild`. The fact that the TextNode was *originally* the child of the `p` is irrelevant -- it's then getting reparented right under `document.body`.

In other words, the sequence of events is:

- Create the `p` element
- Create the text node
- Append the text node to the `p`
- Append the text node to `document.body`

That last step changes where it goes...

Comment: So parent.appendChild(child) returns the child, not the parent?

Comment: Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild "The returned value is the appended child."